# Add CSS overflow if height > some number

Tags: jquery, css

I have a script that upon clicking Search, searches for users, and brings back the list.  The list could be from 1- any number.  I want the list to max out at 400 px in height and add overflow-y: scroll to it.

Is this possible? I have tried adding it to the function that gets the list but it just ignores it.

Comment: Did you try max-height in CSS?

Comment: As @adeneo says just add max-width:400px and overflow-y:scroll (or auto will probably work too) to the div in your css at the start. It should be noted that max-width doesn't work in IE6 or less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was to use the css max-height property.